# What is the Jetpack Compose alternative to JSplitPane?

Tags: draggable, splitpane, compose-desktop

In Swing I use `JSplitPane` to create a region with a tree view to the left(leading) and a region with a hex viewer to the right(trailing) where the user can move the divider to adjust the space each get.

Since Jetpack Compose is still relatively new, basic components like `SplitView` (the hypothetical name for such a component following their naming scheme) don't yet exist. The closest concept I can see is `Row` and `Column` but those are not user-resizable (as far as I can tell.)

Without resorting to embedding a Swing `JSplitPane` and then embedding Compose components in each side of the split pane, is there a good way to do this?

I found [one example](https://gist.github.com/noe/ef6c10a91db79e713f8ca1f7623b11cd) which got me 90% of the way there, but there was some removed API which is incredibly difficult to find the replacement for as the release notes don't appear to even mention it. (!!)

Comment: `onDrag` -> `Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) { detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount -> } }`, `DensityAmbient` -> `LocalDensity`

Comment: To be honest, taking design practices like a resizable pane for a desktop web app and applying them to mobile devices is just bad practice. It is very rare to find a mobile app with split panes. This is just poor design for a mobile app. Material Design doesn't even support that.

Comment: @Johann I'm making a desktop app. To be fair, the tags _do_ say android-jetpack-compose but it didn't seem like there was a plain jetpack-compose tag to choose from.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov that's a good pointer in the right direction, I'll just have to read up on whether passing Unit is acceptable or not because the help docs on that one really make it sound like I'm supposed to pass in a proper ID...

Comment: @Hakanai you need to pass any values on which your calculations depends, which can change during view lifecycle

Comment: There actually is a tag for compose desktop. I replaced your existing tag with it.

Comment: @Johann well spotted, I didn’t expect they would take a word out of the name so I didn’t think to search for it. Still, it would be nice to have one tag covering both too since part of the point of Jetpack Compose is to share code between multiple targets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an official implementation for that. You can add this dependency to your build.gradle:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.compose.components:components-splitpane-desktop:1.0.1'
```

The newest version can be found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.compose.components/components-splitpane-desktop).

There is also a [demo class](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/blob/master/components/SplitPane/demo/src/jvmMain/kotlin/org/jetbrains/compose/splitpane/demo/Main.kt) in the official compose repository that shows how to use it.